# Cannot see all users in Forecast

Tags: forecast

When I'm looking at the forecast tab I cannot see opportunities from other users under me in the Hierarchy.
When I type their name on the upper left side I see only their opportunities.

What do I need to do to see all the pipeline under me?

Comment: Have you enabled customized forecasting?

Comment: I think its enabled